# SoftKeyboard hiding EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a layout that uses an EditText to let users search a database and populate a ListView.  The EditText is about 2/3 of the way from the top of the screen (positioned over an ImageView, and followed by some intro text.)

The problem is that the soft keyboard hides the EditText, so the user can't see what he's typing.  (I disabled the auto-suggest.)

I've tried LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, paddings, and different alignments/centerings, but I still can't get it to work right.  The EditText is either hidden, gets pushed off the top of the screen, or get "squished" and distorted.

Suggestions???

One possible workaround is to move the EditText to the top of the screen.  However, this deviates from the graphic design that I was given.

Another possible workaround is for me to make the soft keyboard open in full screen (not sure how, though).  This will still hide the EditText, but then I can re-enable the auto-suggestion so the user can see what he's typing... sort of... because he can only see the *suggestions* for what he's typing.

Here's my latest attempt.  See "introFrame".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/titleContainer"
  android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TextView android:text="@string/title_string"
   android:textSize="15sp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
   android:textStyle="bold" android:paddingLeft="5dp"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <FrameLayout 
 android:id="@+id/introFrame"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
 <ImageView 
  android:src="@drawable/main_search_image"
  android:scaleType="center"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
 <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:paddingTop="140dp" >
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/introSearchContainer"
   android:orientation="horizontal" 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >
   <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/intro_search_box" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="     Enter keyword     " 
     android:imeOptions="actionGo"   
     android:inputType="textFilter" 
     android:maxLines="1" />
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/intro_search_button" 
     android:background="@drawable/custom_button_go"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  <TextView
   android:text="@string/search_intro"
   android:textSize="15sp"
   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" /> 
 </LinearLayout>
 </FrameLayout>

 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/listContainer"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ListView android:id="@+id/itemlist" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
  <TextView android:text="No data found" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center"
   android:textSize="16sp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:id="@+id/android:empty" />
 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is how it solved my problem
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29408773/3595514

Answer (score 57, accepted):

What you're looking for is the Activity's [`windowSoftInputMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) attribute. You set this in your AndroidManifest.xml file, and give it a value such as:

- `adjustResize`: "The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen."
- `adjustPan`: "The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window."

adjustResize will probably work for you, as long as you wrap the layout in a ScrollView. It may have negative effects if you have a bitmap image in the background, as it will be resized as well, in which case you may want to use adjustPan instead.

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

or

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

More information is available at the above link.

Comment: not working for me in a Fragment as a child of a FragmentActivity.

Comment: this doesn't work when app is running in fullscreen mode

Answer (score 13):

What has worked for me is to drop my highest-level LinearLayout in a scrollView (the ScrollView can only have one child). This allowed the entire activity/form to scroll up and not clutter the EditText in focus.

First, I set in my activity:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Then I did the ScrollView thing I'm talking about:

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- STUFF -->

  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Did not work for me on ICS. Any idea if adding stateHidden to windowSoftInputMode could be causing this problem ?

Comment: not working for me in a Fragment as a child of a FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 3):

just use following in manifest...

```
  <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Answer (score 1):

try giving the edit text a layout_weight  (i.e. layout_weight=1)  , this may have some other effects on your other layout items that you may have to work through, but this may help it stay visible when soft keyboard pops up