# Android softKeyboard hiding EditText when there're too much text

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I know this question has been asked many times, like: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432903/softkeyboard-hiding-edittext), but my issue is a little bit different.  I have set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in manifest.  Normally it works fine.

Because I need the `EditText` show only one line text, so I set:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

As an example, we assume my `EditText` can show 10 chars in one line, when I click the `EditText` and input 9 chars, everything is ok.  When I hide the keyboard and then click the `EditText` again, no problem as well, the keyboard will not hide the input area.

BUT, when I input 15 chars and hide the keyboard, then I click the `EditText` again, if the `cursor` is **After** the 10th char, the keyboard will **hide** the input area, but if i make the `cursor` **Before** the 10th char, everything is ok.

Does anybody know the reason?  Many thanks in advance.