# Keyboard hiding EditTexts in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, samsung-mobile, window-soft-input-mode, imeoptions

**edit: 
I need to use the keyboard, but it hides my `EditText`, I need it to scroll so the keyboard is not hiding it.**

I am using a Samsung tablet.

My style:

```
parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

The `EditText` fields are in a scrollable view, like so:

The fragment layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
         android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
         android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
         android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/depot_code"/>

        <EditText
            android:hint="@string/enter_depot_code"
            android:id="@+id/etlocationId"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLength="12"
            android:singleLine="true">

            <requestFocus/>
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/name"/>

        <EditText
            android:hint="@string/enter_name"
            android:id="@+id/etname"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLength="24"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/street"/>

        <EditText
            android:hint="@string/enter_street"
            android:id="@+id/etstreet"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLength="24"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/suburb"/>

        <EditText
            android:hint="@string/enter_suburb"
            android:id="@+id/etsuburb"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLength="24"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/state"/>

        <Spinner
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/phone"/>

        <EditText
            android:hint="@string/enter_phone"
            android:id="@+id/etphone"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLength="12"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnadd"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

The Activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/tech_controller"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

< .../ Layouts. ../>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Similar questions have been asked, but I have not found an answer that works.

I have a project that uses many fragments attached to the one activity.
In my manifest for the activity I have:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Some of the fragments require user input.

In the fragment layout I use:

Each fragment is nested as follows:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" .../>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            or
            android:imeOptions="actionDone" .../>
```

This works well. EXCEPT
the keyboard hides the EditTexts that are positioned lower on the page.

[image]

I have read this over and over:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions

Tried these suggestions, but the keyboard is then visible when the activity is called, which I don't want. It also does not work. Maybe because it is a fragment?

[SoftKeyboard hiding EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432903/softkeyboard-hiding-edittext)

[Android Keyboard hides EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262414/android-keyboard-hides-edittext)

I have been trying to work out a dynamic solution. Any help is appreciated.

**edit: This is for use on tablets and there is only one keyboard option, with language changes.**

---

**Edit: MY SOLUTION**

I have solved it by installing another soft keyboard. https://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/wiki/HowTo

Comment: can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: The IME you used has it's own "floating" layout, can you try your code with built-in IMEs like Google Keyboard or set your IME to a normal full-width layout?

Comment: @Heyyou  long press on the space bar button in the keyboard.  thgis will bring up a dialog that will give you a chooser where you may select another keyboard.

Comment: @Heyyou try settings > language and input > and look for keyboards

Comment: are you using `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);` flag or any other flag to full-screen your activity?

Comment: Try clearing flag in `onCreate()` as `getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to call `InputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow()` during your fragment's `onActivityCreated()` function mentioned in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9981958)?

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    AppUtil.hideKeyboard(getActivity(), getView());
}
```

where `hideKeyboard()` looks like this

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity, View viewToHide) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(viewToHide.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try to use `WindowsSoftInputMode` as `adjustpan` only.

For ex:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to put this in onActivityCreated of your fragment:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

This should not make the keyboard upon loading or starting of your activity with fragment.

Comment: Try to add this in your android manifest in addition to my previous answer:
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`
I think it will work :)

Comment: You may try this also 
`getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);`

Comment: Hello @Heyyou, just my hunch maybe there's a conflict between scrollview and the soft input keyboard :) Anyway, hope you find the solution. I will get back here when I have my solution again ^_^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83179/discussion-between-joey-and-hey-you).

Answer (score 4):

I have tried this code and resolve my issue.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by installing another soft keyboard, via the google play store.

It was [Petey's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794088/petey) comments that made me explore this solution.

> The IME you used has it's own "floating" layout, can you try your code with built-in IMEs like Google Keyboard or set your IME to a normal full-width layout?

So I figured, no amount of playing with the view layout was going to affect a soft keyboard that has an independent layout.

I used this link https://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/wiki/HowTo

It even works with Android Manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

I then use `imeoptions` to control the flow of the editor cursor within the view.

**edit update**

I just tried the app on a no-brand android tablet, which comes with comes with a generic android keyboard and it works, without having to change a thing. It seems the Samsung default keyboard is painful.

Answer (score 1):

**Change this to LinearLayout**:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

to

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
```

(and the closing tag). Note the orientation.

**Update the manifest Remove this**:

```
<application ... >
    <activity
      android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan">
        ...
    </activity>
    ...
</application>
```

**Change this (height)**:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
```

Comment: @Heyyou can you add your full xml. I am interested in the parent layouts

Comment: @Heyyou I tried your XML (with linearlayout) in a new project and it works prefectly. I made one more edit. Try removing that from the mainifest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83181/discussion-between-prakharsingh95-and-hey-you).

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that hide keyboard does not work with
getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

Answer (score 0):

Before show your **Snackbar** widget hide the keyboard like this,

```
public void showSnackBar(){ 
InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(),0); 
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getView(), "Some message!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show(); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was using the ScrollView the same way as you in my FrameLayout, in which I added this property: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan". At the end, it looks like this and it is working. I did not need to change anything programatically:

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProductFragment"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
      ...
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode ? It is absolute wrong.